# MongoDB Change Stream watcher has been fired on second execution of aws-lambda function or has not been fired at all

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am building Angular PWA app with nodejs server. After few investigations I decided to put my front-end on S3 and back-end on aws-lambda using serverless-framework and connect it with mongo atlas.

In my back-end I use `mongoose.watch()` to listen for appropriate changes in my DB. On change happenes I use FCM to send data to device according to token.

Once app is launched I send 3-4 requests (different pathes) to get data from my DB.

So here is my issue:

If I use `sls offline start --skipCacheInvalidation` to work locally everything works almost fine - I received 2 or more dublications, so it seems like each my starting requests begin aws-lambda function.

Once I `sls deploy` I get all my starting data, but once I update DB (by another request) in aws-lambda logs streams I don't see that my code reach `.on('change')` listener. And aws-lambda request execution ends. Sometimes my code reaches this listener, and print change stream data of my previous request.

Here is part of my **serverless.yml**

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 30
  versionFunctions: false

functions:
  app:
    handler: server.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /{proxy+}
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent
              - x-customauthheader
            allowCredentials: false
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './variables.env' });
const sls = require('serverless-http');
const app = require('./lib/app');
module.exports.handler = sls(app, { callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: false });
```

**app.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// // Allow CORS support and remote requests to the service
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

const { checkHeaders } = require('../bin/routes-handler');
app.use(checkHeaders);

require('./db');
const routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

**db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useFindAndModify: false },
);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection Error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('mongoose Connection established');
  require('../services/quote-watcher')(db);
});
```

and my **quote-watcher.js**

```
const { sendDataByTokens } = require('../bin/notify-devices');

module.exports = db => {
  'use strict';
  const taskCollection = db.collection('quotes');
  const changeStream = taskCollection.watch([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });
  // const changeStream = taskCollection.watch();

  changeStream.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  changeStream.on('change', change => {
    console.log(change);
    if (change.operationType === 'insert') {
      return sendDataByTokens(
        change.fullDocument.participants,
        change.operationType,
        change.fullDocument,
        change.ns.coll,
        null,
        { stage: change.fullDocument.currStage },
      );
    }
    if (change.operationType === 'update') {
      const { updatedFields } = change.updateDescription;
      return sendDataByTokens(
        change.fullDocument.participants,
        change.operationType,
        change.fullDocument,
        change.ns.coll,
        change.documentKey._id,
        { stage: change.fullDocument.currStage, updatedFields },
      );
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Hello D.Kurapin, I have the same Issue. I think the problem is, that aws lambda finishes code execution after the response of the backend. Your watcher is running as a stream, but always detects changes after the backend already responded. this could be the reason, why you sometimes still see a log from your watcher even when your watcher doesn't fully executes the whole code. I'm looking for a solution maybe a design pattern to actually let the watcher call the finish of the lambda process

Comment: @sami_analyst. Thanks for your opinion. Ithought about it as well, but I didn't find a solution as well. So that decided to put everything on EC2 instance

Comment: As a momentary solution, You can Set a timeout in your Response. Set this timeout only on the Routers, where your Stream watcher would bei teiggered. But of course, ec2 is a good solution too

Comment: I need more workable solution than using timeouts. Update me if you find something. I can't promise that I will need it, but it will be interesting to read.